# What is the real chance my 8-week puppy gets parvo?

Tags: dogs, medicines, diseases, infections

I have an 8-week old cocker spaniel - poodle mix. I'm told she's had her first parvo shot out of three.

I live in a relatively well-to-do neighborhood with very, very few stray dogs. We have a front yard and a back yard, with the backyard completely gated and dog-proof. The gate joins the house where the front and back yard meet, probably about forty feet between the sidewalk/road and that gate.

For a couple reasons, we really didn't want to let the puppy go to the bathroom in the backyard a few minutes ago (minutes-old tree spray, probably innocuous but playing it safe).

We got lucky and the puppy didn't want to go to the bathroom before the spray dried out (really super hot here). But if she *had* (because this will probably come up again): **What is the real chance my puppy gets parvo** if I had let her relieve on my front lawn? How common is it among dogs, and do more dogs come that far up on my lawn than I think? How much does that first shot do?

Comment: Most dogs did just fine before the vaccine was available... and the first shot confers some resistance. I wouldn't worry too much about this incidental exposure. But I'm a cat person, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: Pretty much zero chance. By the way, the 8 to 12 week period is critical for socialization. so get your puppy to kindergarten puppy training class and try to meet as many vaccinated dogs as possible. Stay away from a dog park, but don't be overly afraid of your dog catching a disease and keep them isolated.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't take the chance. Parvo killed my puppy. If you live in a nice neighborhood then I would definitely get the other 2 shots. Parvo has no bounds and if any of you neighbor's board their animals while going on vacation then there you go, a possible outbreak.